# Getting error installing ionic-native with npm

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, npm

I am getting this npm / Angular error:

```
$ npm install ionic-native --save
boardline@1.0.0 /home/louisro/Documents/mobileApps/BoardLine/ionic_version
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@>=2.0.0-rc.0 <2.0.0-rc.5
└── ionic-native@2.2.16 

npm WARN @ionic/cloud-angular@0.4.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=2.0.0-rc.0 <2.0.0-rc.5 but none was installed.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: did you try removing ``npm_modules`` and reinstalling.

Comment: no, but am I gonna loose all my npm modules doing this ?

Comment: no, I don't where is this directory, I just see `node_modules`in my project root

Comment: All the dependencies should be mentioned in ``package.json`` . When you do ``npm install``  , modules will be rebuilt . default ionic project already have ``ionic-native``

Comment: sorry i meant ``node_modules``

Comment: Ok I see the dir,  but will I have to reinstall all the node modules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove `node_modules` and reinstall packages with `npm install`. This would look for all the dependencies in `dependencies` attribute of `package.json` and install them.

How does `package.json` know the dependencies of your project? Well you asked it to ( or should have ). When you do `npm install <pkg-name> --save` it install the package in `node_modules` and `--save` adds it in `package.json` `dependencies`.

So an `npm install` would add all the packages back that are mentioned in `package.json` and its dependencies too. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Louis happy to help.